# How to postback with PHP

Tags: php, callback, postback

I get this url to my php server:

```
https://example.com/index.php?status=1&trans_id=10081975462&user_id=WrUbd8WXgrcVrvP0AtaSgHmatMw2&amount_local=175.0000&amount_usd=0.50&offer_id=1&hash=59e5e01bb8d43a59dfa916de06aab9eb&ip_click=78.122.32.238
```

To retrieve the parameters from query URL I did like this :

```
$status = $_GET['status'];
$trans_id = $_GET['trans_id'];
$user_id = $_GET['user_id'];
$amount_local = $_GET['amount_local'];
$amount_usd = $_GET['amount_usd'];
$offer_id = $_GET['offer_ID'];
$hash = $_GET['secure_hash'];
$ip_click = $_GET['ip_click'];
```

Then the documentation tells me this:

**{secure_hash} here we had a hash that you can validate the request the hash is a md5 hash:**

**example: md5({trans_id}-yourappsecurehash)**

{secure_hash} it's `$hash = $_GET['secure_hash'];`

`yourappsecurehash` it's my private hash associated with my application visibly in my dashboard

I'm not sure I understood this section correctly, but here is my code:

```
$app_secure_hash = "xxxxxxxxxxx";

if (md5($status.$trans_id.$user_id.$amount_local.$amount_usd.$offer_id.$hash.$ip_click) != $app_secure_hash) {
        
   echo "500";
       
} else {

   echo "200";
       
}
```

It always returns `echo "500";`

**Do you have a solution ?**

*Below is a photo of the weak documentation on the website*

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAhrj.jpg

Comment: Is it true that you only need to md5 the `{trans_id}-yourappsecurehash` ? (and **not** to perform md5 on $status.$trans_id.$user_id.$amount_local.$amount_usd.$offer_id..... )

Answer (score 0):

From the document you only has to check `trans_id` and not all parameters. Also you may have to change condition. So try below code

```
$app_secure_hash = "xxxxxxxxxxx";

if (md5($trans_id.'-'.$app_secure_hash) != $hash) {
        
   echo "500";
       
} else {

   echo "200";
       
}
```